# NPM Publish suddenly stopped working with 403 (verified email, unique name & version, no proxy, automation token)

Tags: node.js, npm, publish, http-status-code-403

I've been publishing a private scoped NPM package.
The publishing process was automated in AWS CI pipeline.
It's been working fine for a while then publishing just stopped working with 403 error one day. There were no change in CI pipeline whatsoever.
These are what I have tried:

- renewing token (both automation and publish)
- changing version numbers to something unique
- changing package access/publish access
- publishing from local computer
- publishing from local computer with different authorized account
- tried different versions of NPM 6~8
- NPM audit fix --force
- re-installing node_modules

They all failed with the same 403 error.

What else can I try? Please help.

Answer (score 0):

**It was a temporary issue**. It went back normal after a while. I guess something was going on in the NPM server.

Comment: I had the same issue now with my package that is published with GitHub Actions. It just stop working since yesterday. I have tried all the step you described but they all failed with the same 403 error. How many time did you have to wait until your package can be re-published ?